# List JSON array in MySQL as rows

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column `AddressIdentifiers` of JSON type in my MySQL table `Customers` and the data sample looks like:

```
[
  {
    "code": "123",
    "identifier": "0219d5780f6b",
    "type": "BILLING",
    "info": null
  },
  {
    "code": "240",
    "identifier": "c81aaf2c5a1f",
    "type": "DELIVERY",
    "info": null
  }
]
```

I am using query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(AddressIdentifiers, '$**.identifier') As Identifier, JSON_EXTRACT(AddressIdentifiers, '$**.type') As AddressType FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = 10003;
```

to get output like:

```
Identifier   AddressType
------------------------
0219d5780f6b  BILLING
c81aaf2c5a1f  DELIVERY
```

But it does not give output like table rows instead gives concatenated values. How can we get the output from the JSON array like rows (as above)? Please advise.

I am using MySQL version `5.7.17`.

Thanks,
Prabhat

EDIT-1:
I think if we join this `Customers` table with `Address` table (having columns: Id, identifier, Address, City, Pincode) that has the `identifier` as key then may be we can pull these values as row for each address?

So output will be something like:

```
 Identifier   AddressType   Address  City
    -----------------------------------------
    0219d5780f6b  BILLING      Address-1  Hyderabad
    c81aaf2c5a1f  DELIVERY     Address-2  Delhi
```

Comment: A good solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153230/5381704

Answer (score 4):

I have this solution for MySQL 5.7, where you have to do the work manually. In the case of MySQL 8.0+ you can simply use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table)

```
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(C.AddressIdentifiers, CONCAT('$[', Numbers.N - 1, '].Identifier')) AS Identifier,
    JSON_EXTRACT(C.AddressIdentifiers, CONCAT('$[', Numbers.N - 1, '].AddressType')) AS AddressType,
FROM
(
    SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS N FROM 
    (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) T2,
    (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) T1, 
    (SELECT @row:=0) T0
) Numbers -- Natural numbers from 1 to 100
INNER JOIN Customers C ON Numbers.N <= JSON_LENGTH(C.AddressIdentifiers)
```